# Chrome pdf viewer crashes after 5 - 10 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, pdf-viewer

When I open a pdf file (e.g. https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) the file is shown:
[image]

but after 5 - 10 seconds it crashes, (whether I'm doing something in the meantime or not) :

[image]

My operation system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (64-bit), processor Intel Core2 Duo, Chrome version 87.0.4280.66. (32-bit)

How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the latest version of Adobe PDF Viewer installed?

Suggest the following:
Install the latest Adobe PDF Viewer

- https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html

If it still crashes, try Lubmin PDF

- https://www.luminpdf.com/

If it still crashes, try 64-bit version of Google Chrome

- https://www.google.com/chrome/

If it still crashes, try installing latest version of Firefox browser

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/